# Revisiting passing type as parameter

Tags: c#

Without generics, I'd like to pass a type as a function parameter **without instantiating the type**.  The handling function should be able to restrict the type, such as (using System.Enum as an example, could be any type though):

```
enum QuestionTypes { Great, Good, Huh, Dumb, Dumber }
// error - "QuestionTypes is a type but used like a variable"
static void Main(string[] args) { TypeHandler(QuestionTypes); }
static void TypeHandler(System.Enum enumType) { /* do stuff */ }
```

This is not the same as passing the type name, a string, or an instance.  It seems reasonable that .NET should be able to pass a type, since the definition exists in compiled code.  Is this a job only for reflection, or can it be done without?

Comment: like: Type theType = typeof(YourType)?  what all is going on in "do stuff"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So....pass a [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) parameter?

```
static void MyFunction(Type t)
{
  ...
}

MyFunction(typeof(QuestionTypes));
```

Comment: That's how I started out, but looking to restrict the passed type, i.e. System.String, System.Byte, or as above, System.Enum, such that ( as I should've named the example), TypeHandler() could be ByteTypeHandler(System.Byte sb), etc.

Comment: @RobertKerr: Then you need to work your way up the tree. Type is the base of all types.

Comment: Ah, because QuestionTypes is a type of System.Type, not a type of System.Enum?  Wait, I still don't comprehend.  System.Type <-- System.Enum <-- QuestionTypes.

Comment: @RobertKerr: I think you're better off looking in to generics (though I'm still not 100% sure what you're going for here). -- And to answer your question, the Type class is just a representation of the datatype, less the logic. It's just a structural outline basically.

Comment: You're almost there, I appreciate you hanging with me.  I'll clarify further.  If QuestionTypes has a type chain of System.Enum and further up System.Type, and you (and others) are suggesting making System.Type as the handling function's parameter type, it should be equally viable to require the function parameter to be System.Enum.

Comment: @RobertKerr: But it's not. Type acts like a base, but the types don't do inheritance like a class does. Think of it like a sketched drawing of a type, instead of a building block.